# Is it possible to set a VPN through Tor? and have functionality for Software Updates?

Tags: networking, updates, software-center, vpn, tor

Gday,

I have been trying to do a software update on Trusty both on terminal and software update app but that hasnt been successful, apparently my ISP has a broken transparent proxy.

```
moazhmi@moazhmi-K52F:~$ wget -S http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease
--2014-06-04 17:34:52-- http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease
Resolving extras.ubuntu.com (extras.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.92.152
Connecting to extras.ubuntu.com (extras.ubuntu.com)|91.189.92.152|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
  Content-Length: 213
  Date: Wed, 04 Jun 2014 14:34:52 GMT
  Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
Length: 213 [text/html]
Saving to: ‘InRelease’

100%[======================================>] 213 --.-K/s in 0s

2014-06-04 17:34:52 (22.1 MB/s) - ‘InRelease’ saved [213/213]
```

I was advised to refer back to the ISP with a complaint but that has returned with peanuts.

My Question is -

Is it possible to set a VPN through TOR , i.e whereas I can run software updates through terminals or the app . the browsing is out of question here as I need to update which I am not able to do / only on 12.04.

Comment: See [syntax for SOCKS proxy in apt.conf](http://askubuntu.com/questions/35223/syntax-for-socks-proxy-in-apt-conf) and [Apt-get update through tor](http://askubuntu.com/questions/381377/apt-get-update-through-tor)