# Redirect terminal through tor?

Tags: command-line, tor

There are some sources blocked in my country.  So when I do `apt-get update` I get th ane error below:

```
alexander@Alexander-PC:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for alexander: 
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg           
Get:1 http://dl.google.com stable InRelease [1,540 B]                
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                
100% [1 InRelease gpgv 1,540 B] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] [WaSplitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stabIgn http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
E: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
alexander@Alexander-PC:~$ ^C
```

when I use proxy it works perfectly.  Now I don't have any proxy can I use TOR ?

My question is: can I redirect the terminal through tor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apt-get update through tor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/381377/apt-get-update-through-tor)

Answer (score 1):

If you set the proxy to use at the system level, almost *all* network requests (regardless of program origin) will be routed through the proxy. Tor is, simply put, a more complex proxy.

Note that, according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/381377/apt-get-update-through-tor?rq=1) you may get an error if you use Google's repo.

Answer (score 0):

Proxy:
Try the following procedure

- set   127.0.0.1:9050 (tor port, may be something else for you )in System -> Preferences -> Network Proxy
- [torify](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3918/how-to-anonymize-the-programs-from-the-terminal) is tool that attempts to wrap your terminal command in a Tor session. There's a good tutorial on what you need to do, [here](https://linuxaria.com/howto/how-to-anonymize-the-programs-from-your-terminal-with-torify). Then it's just a case of running:

  torify
- Using [Proxychains](https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/hack-like-pro-evade-detection-using-proxychains-0154619/)

Comment: `torify` (as well as `torsocks`) should **not** be used. When they can't securely handle a system call made by an application running in them, they simply don't actually perform the system call, which, with `apt install`, `apt upgrade`, or `apt dist-upgrade`, can ruin installations and upgrades of software without APT noticing the problem.